# IE8 jQuery error line:2 char:36689

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, runtime-error

I have this error that really got me crazy.
Everything work just fine in all the browsers except for the IE8 or less.
This is my HTML code:

```
<form id="rentForm" method="post" action="rentsubmit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<select id="rentmake" name="make" class="selectFields">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
<select id="rentmodel" name="model" class="selectFields">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1 Series">1 Series</option>
<option value="2 Series">2 Series</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="rentcolor" name="color" class="fields" />
<input type="text" name="interiorcolor" id="rentinteriorcolor" class="fields" />
<input type="text" id="rentmilage" name="milage" class="fields"/>

<input type="text" id="rentdailyprice" name="dailyprice" class="fields"/>

<input type="text" id="rentweeklyprice" name="weeklyprice" class="fields"/>

<input type="text" id="rentmonthlyprice" name="monthlyprice" class="fields"/>

<input type="text" name="mobilenumber" id="rentmobilenumber" class="fields" />
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="rentphonenumber" class="fields" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="rentemail" class="fields" />
<input type="file" name="photo1" id="rentphoto1" />
<input type="file" name="photo2" id="rentphoto2" />
<input type="file" name="photo3" id="rentphoto3" />
<input type="file" name="photo4" id="rentphoto4" />
<input type="file" name="photo5" id="rentphoto5" />
<input type="file" name="photo6" id="rentphoto6" />
<div id="rentFinish">Finish</div>
<div id="rentPreFinishSpan"></div>
</form>
```

And here's the javaScript responding to it:

```
$('#rentFinish').click(function(){
if($('#rentcolor').val()!=='' && $('#rentinteriorcolor').val()!=='' && $('#rentdailyprice').val()!=='' && $('#rentweeklyprice').val()!=='' && $('#rentmonthlyprice').val()!=='' && $('#rentmilage').val()!==''){
    if($('#rentmobilenumber').val()=='' && $('#rentphonenumber').val()=='' && $('#rentemail').val()==''){
        $(this).next('div').fadeOut().html("Please enter 1 contact info at least").fadeIn();
    }
    else{
if($('#rentphoto1').val()=='' && $('#rentphoto2').val()=='' && $('#rentphoto3').val()=='' && $('#rentphoto4').val()=='' && $('#rentphoto5').val()=='' && $('#rentphoto6').val()=='' )
{
    $(this).next('div').fadeOut().html("please upload 1 photo at least").fadeIn();
}
else{
if($('#rentmake').val()=='0' || $('#rentmodel').val()=='0'){
        $(this).next('div').fadeOut().html("Please select car make and model").fadeIn();
    }
    else{

$('#rentForm').submit();
    }}
}}
else{
    $(this).next('div').fadeOut().html("All fields are required").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

When '#rentFinish' button is clicked, the js will check if the first 6 form fields are not empty, and then check for at least one contact information field, and then at least one photo, if everything is ok the form will be submitted as you see in the js.

That works perfectly in all browsers except for IE8.
In IE8, an error occurs when the compiler reaches the part that handle that form submitting, THIS PART:

```
$('#rentForm').submit();
```

And the error is: Access is denied, jQuery-1.8.2.min.js error line:2 char:36689
I tried and researched about this but i got nothing, can anyone help please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you normally get this in Ajax call in ie8. but you not doing, is it your full code??

Comment: @Eez this is the code that envolved with this form, the rest is irrelevant. And the crazy thing is: if I remove the part that checks for the photos in the js code; it works fine, so I think the problem is in that particular photo checking code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you edit the layout code for this question?.. if so there are more than a handful of errors in your html. If not, validate and your problem may resolve. The following were changed from your original markup.

Extra spaces in form enctype.

type="text" declared in multiple select tags.

multiple closing select tags that have no opening tag were removed.

lone table cell tag removed.

```
<form id="rentForm" method="post" action="rentsubmit.php" enctype="multipart/formdata"> 
<select id="rentmake" name="make" class="selectFields">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
</select>
<select id="rentmodel" name="model" class="selectFields">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1 Series">1 Series</option>
<option value="2 Series">2 Series</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="rentcolor" name="color" class="fields" />
<input type="text" name="interiorcolor" id="rentinteriorcolor" class="fields" />
<input type="text" id="rentmilage" name="milage" class="fields"/>
<input type="text" id="rentdailyprice" name="dailyprice" class="fields"/>
<input type="text" id="rentweeklyprice" name="weeklyprice" class="fields"/>
<input type="text" id="rentmonthlyprice" name="monthlyprice" class="fields"/>
<input type="text" name="mobilenumber" id="rentmobilenumber" class="fields" />
<input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="rentphonenumber" class="fields" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="rentemail" class="fields" />
<input type="file" name="photo1" id="rentphoto1" />
<input type="file" name="photo2" id="rentphoto2" />
<input type="file" name="photo3" id="rentphoto3" />
<input type="file" name="photo4" id="rentphoto4" />
<input type="file" name="photo5" id="rentphoto5" />
<input type="file" name="photo6" id="rentphoto6" />
<div id="rentFinish">Finish</div>
<div id="rentPreFinishSpan"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry for that, i removed the extra spaces and the type="text" and the td and the closing select tag, it's because there's a table in the code and i didn't want to post all of the code including the unnecessary elements.

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SXvm6/ does your code now work in IE8 (I don't have a machine w/IE8 here sorry.)